# angular 5 and node.js express prod build issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I ran into a problem when I tried to do a production build of my angular and node.js project.
When I run my angular project with the command `ng serve`, and backend with`nodemon server`, everything works fine. But when I do `ng build --prod` and modify my backend to pick up statics from" dist ". I do not get the full functionality of the application, I normally have a registration page and login page, but there is a problem with the profile page. On this page, the user's personal information should be displayed, but on the response date from the server I get an empty body and the status is 200 OK.
Below I quote excerpts from my code and screenshots of the inspector.
Help please understand what the problem is.
I would be grateful for any advice.

sevice :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {User} from './user';

@Injectable()
export class MntApiService {
  private data: any = [];
  private mntAPI = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor( private _http: HttpClient ) {
  }

  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get<any>( this.mntAPI + '/users' );
  }

  addUser( user: User ): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post<any>( this.mntAPI + '/signup', user );
  }

  addEditUser( id, user: User ): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post<any>( this.mntAPI + '/profile/' + id, user );
  }

  getById( id: string ): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get( this.mntAPI + '/profile/' + id, {responseType: 'json'} )
      .do( data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log( data );
      } )
      .catch( this.handleError );
  }

  private handleError( err: HttpErrorResponse ) {
    console.log( err );
    return Observable.throw( err.message );
  }
}
```

component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MntApiService} from '../mnt-api.service';

import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

@Component( {
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './user-profile.component.scss' ]
} )
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: {
    user: [
      {
        email?: string;
        password?: string;
        first_name?: string;
        last_name?: string;
        phone_number?: string;
        smartkontract_id?: string;
        country?: string;
        city?: string;
      }
      ]
  };
  private token: string = localStorage.getItem( 'id_token' );
  private tokenPayload: any = jwt_decode( this.token ) || null;

  private id = this.tokenPayload.userId;

  constructor( private mntApiService: MntApiService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser( this.id );
  }


  getUser( id ) {
    this.mntApiService.getById( id )
      .subscribe( users => {
        this.data = users;
      } );
  }
}
```

node.js file users.js

```
router.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';

  config.query(sql, id, (err, user) => {
    console.log(user);
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: err
      });
      return;
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        user: user
      });
    }
  });
});
```

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.1.3",
    "node-mysql": "^0.4.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const usersRoutes = require('./api/routes/users');


app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res ) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.Header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.Header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});



app.use('/', usersRoutes);


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error('Not found');
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

and screenshots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH0ba.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUVs9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlnZY.png)

Comment: From the first screenshots, the error means you are receiving **html**  response from server (the `error message` and `text` content). The second screenshot confirmed it (at `response header` section it says `Content-Type: text/html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the above comment, your app is receiving html response from server (the error message and text content). The second screenshot confirmed it (at response header section it says Content-Type: text/html.

A quick fix would be to specify response **`Accept: text/html`** in the headers request you send to your server. Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable() 
export class YOURService{

  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "Accept": "text/html"  // <-- add this
  });


constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get<any>( this.mntAPI + '/users', {headers: this.headers} );
  }

}
```

Let me know how you go with that?

**Or specify at server side**

```
router.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?';

  config.query(sql, id, (err, user) => {
    console.log(user);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // <-- set header here
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
        message: err
      }));
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ // <-- send JSON data here
        user: user
      }));
    }
  });
});
```

**Updated on app.js**
You should remove the code block (commented out lines) in your `app.js` as they redirect all your `get` request to your server incorrectly in production mode. Something as below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const usersRoutes = require('./api/routes/users');

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// ======= This should be removed ========================
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
// res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
// });
// =======================================================

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {

  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
             'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/', usersRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error('Not found');
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({error : {message : error.message}});
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it did not help, it's the same error and the empty request body. The matter is that my server sends data in a format json and I do not understand why in headings the answer in a format text / html. I tried to find the error in the console at least a simple "hello world" after the line [link]router.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log('hello world');
;[link]but it does not print to the console, although the response is correct [link] GET / profile / 24,200 1.276 ms - 681 [link]. but after the answer my "hello world" @sugarme

Comment: can you do something at your node.js server: **res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');** and 
    **res.send(JSON.stringify({ user: user }));** ? And don't set "Accept": "text/html" at your Angular app.

Comment: Again it did not help, the above I added the file code app.js. to the problem description.
It just kills me, why the server does not send data in the right format. I can give a link to the git project repository, if this can help. Only by personal message.

Comment: Feel free to send me pm.

Comment: There are no personal messages here, let me know your contact information, for example email. @sugarme

Comment: my email prianikc@gmail.com for @sugarme

Comment: Please send at ngxdemo@gmail.com.

Comment: Thanks for the help,
for the future in app.js you also need to add app.use ('/ your-path', express.static (path.join (__ dirname, 'dist'))); and everything works fine.